# Connection timed out when i try connect to EC2 via SSH on port 22 from my machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, debian

I can't connect to an EC2 via ssh on my machine (Debian 12) but I can establish an ssh connection from one EC2 to another using EC2 instance connect.

When I run the following command on my machine...

`sudo ssh -i my-key.pem ec2-user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

I receive the following response:

`OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u2, OpenSSL 3.0.11 19 Sep 2023 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for * debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22. debug1: connect to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out`

But when I access an EC2 via EC2 instance connect and use the same command to access another EC2 I can access it perfectly.

The 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' represents the public dns host or also the public IP. I tried with both.

Comment: Have you authorized inbound connections on port 22 for that instance?

Comment: Did you add the security group inbound to allow SSH that includes your current ip address or all ip address ?

Comment: SSH is enabled on port 22 for any external access to the security group (yes, it's not a good practice, but I did this just to test). I also released other ports for web access (8080 for example) and was able to access the application perfectly.

Comment: I am a little confused when you say "one EC2", "an EC2" and "another EC2". Let's call your instances `Instance-A` and `Instance-B`. You are saying that you cannot SSH from your own computer on the Internet to `Instance-A`. Are you using EC2 Instance Connect to login to the _same_ instance (`Instance-A`) or are you connecting to the _other_ instance (`Instance-B`)? And then which instance are you connecting to after making the initial connection with EC2 Instance Connect and are you connecting to that instance via its **public IP address** or its **private IP address**?

Comment: Both instance A and instance B have access via ssh on port 22 (AWS standard) to any address (0.0.0.0/0).
I can't access it through my computer, but when I connect to instance A via EC2 instance connect and through it I try to connect to instance B using the public IP/DNS that I can connect to.

Comment: I'd recommend using **VPC Reachability Analyzer**, hidden in the **Network Manager** menu, to check connectivity from the IGW to the instance `B`. Leave all IP address details except the destination port (`22`) unset to start.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!!!

Everything was fine in the AWS configuration, I just had to change the port in the security group to another (port 22 is blocked by default in some cases) and within EC2 I edited the configuration regarding the port, restarted the service and connected successfully.

Thank you for your help!